# general topology: closure, int, derivative inf, sup, of a sequence

Tags: general-topology

I'm working on some exercises on topology on a book I found. What I'm trying to find is the $\operatorname{Int}{X}$, $\partial{X}$, $\bar{X}$, ${X}'$, $\inf X$ and $\sup X$. And if the terms of the sequence form an open or closed set.
Consider the following set $X=\{ x_n \mid n \in \Bbb N \}$ where
\begin{align*}
x_{n} =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{n} + 2   & \text{if n is even}\\\\ 
\dfrac{n}{n+1} - 1 & \text{if n is odd}&
\end{cases}.
\end{align*}

The topology that we are working is the usual topology in $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: In English, what you call a "succession" is called "sequence". You only defined $x_n$, but what is $X$?

Comment: @amsmath I'm sorry, I speak Spanish. Thank you for the correction. X is the same as $x_{n}$, I guess that is a typo from the exercise.

Comment: "X is the same as $x_n$" - So, $X$ is a number? Surely not. When we speak about topology, we speak about sets. So, what's the set that $X$ stands for?

Comment: It's almost certainly the case that $X= \{x_n \mid n \in \Bbb N \}$.

Comment: What techniques are available to you to show that a set is open or is closed?  I'm asking because your answers are not all correct, and rather than giving you the answer, my preference is to give you the tools to see the answer for yourself.  Also, I assume $\bar{X}$ is the closure of $X$, but I'm not familiar with the notation $X'$ in this context.  What does it mean?

Comment: @RobertShore, yeah, exactly. Thank you.

Comment: @RobertShore by definition and using properties, such as a set F \subseteq R is said to be closed iff its complement is open.

Comment: So what tools are available to you to know that a set is open?

Comment: @RobertShore the notation for $X'$ stands for the derivative of the set which are the accumulation points, and for an open set I also have properties and the fact that every open ball in Rn is an open set

Comment: What is your definition of "accumulation point"?  Please **edit the question** to show how you applied your definitions to reach your answers.  That will help us see where you're going wrong (and you are) and allow us to give you targeted help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't written the topological space in which you are workin. For different spaces you may have different results.

However, let suppose that we work in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology.
Then, notice that your set is defined using a sequence, hence all terms of the sequence belong to the set.

Since you are using a book, you can refer to the definitions of the notions you want to find there.

By the definition of the interior of the set, yes $Int X= \emptyset .$
Before answering the other questions, notice that the given sequence is constructed with the help of two monotone bounded subsequences $a_k =\frac{1}{2k}+2=\frac{4k+1}{2k}$ and $b_k=\frac{2k-1}{2k}-1=-\frac{1}{2k}$. The limits of these two subsequences are $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k=2$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty}b_k=0$, hence $\overline{X}=X\cup\{2,0\}, \; \partial{X}=X\cup\{2,0\}, \; X'=\{2,0\}, \; \sup(X)=\max(X)=2+\frac{1}{2}$ and $\inf(X)=\min(X)=-\frac{1}{2}$.

If you need more detailed answer for any of these please write down in the comment.

Comment: Thank you! It was really helpful

Comment: What exactly is the derivative of the set? Are those the same as the limits of the sequence?

Comment: @Javier Fernando Vivas Camargo You can better undertand the derivative of the set as the closure of the set minus the isolation points of the set. The definition of the derivative of the set X is: $x\in X'$ if for any open neighborhood U of $x\in X$, $(U \backslesh \{ x\} ) \cap X \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: That was pretty helpful! Finally I understand, thank you!